# indexing to fill a preallocated pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have a (simple) problem with indexing: I have a preallocated array and want to fill it with calculated values for further processing. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

meanMov = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(3),index=range(20))

value1 = np.array([23.5,-42.34,322.4])
value2 = np.array([43,-764.56,6.4556])
value3 = np.array([98.54,-26.64,86.45])

meanMov.iloc[0:5] = value1
meanMov.iloc[5:15] = value2
meanMov.iloc[15:20] = value3
```

This results in the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value
```

How can I fix this?? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You seem to know how many times each array is to be repeated. Is that actually the case? This seems a tedious way to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pre-initialise. You can just call `repeat` with a list of repeat values, and create your final DataFrame after.

```
r = [5, 10, 5]
v = [value1, value2, value3]
```

```
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(v, r, axis=0))

        0       1         2
0   23.50  -42.34  322.4000
1   23.50  -42.34  322.4000
2   23.50  -42.34  322.4000
3   23.50  -42.34  322.4000
4   23.50  -42.34  322.4000
5   43.00 -764.56    6.4556
6   43.00 -764.56    6.4556
7   43.00 -764.56    6.4556
8   43.00 -764.56    6.4556
9   43.00 -764.56    6.4556
10  43.00 -764.56    6.4556
11  43.00 -764.56    6.4556
12  43.00 -764.56    6.4556
13  43.00 -764.56    6.4556
14  43.00 -764.56    6.4556
15  98.54  -26.64   86.4500
16  98.54  -26.64   86.4500
17  98.54  -26.64   86.4500
18  98.54  -26.64   86.4500
19  98.54  -26.64   86.4500
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this elegant way which is indeed much faster! But now I figured out another problem with a dynamic value, here is an example:

`data = np.random.rand(50,3)`

`r = [15, 20, 15]`
`v = [value1, value2, value3]`
   
`value1 = (data[0:15]).mean(axis=0)`
`value3 = (data[35:50]).mean(axis=0)`
`value2 = []`
`for j in range(15,35):
    value2.append((data[(j-eps):(j+eps+1)]).mean(axis=0))`
    
`pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(v, r, axis=0))`

is there a way to put value2 using np.repeat to the pd.DataFrame?

Comment: @osteocyt I'm not sure I follow... what exactly is tripping you up? You've already defined v, now you're trying to overwrite the arrays?

Comment: the problem is that value2 is now 'dynamic' which means it consists of 20 triples of numbers as produced by the for-loop, not only one triple as in value1 and value3. Therefore, the range of value2 should consist different numbers in my final dataframe

Comment: @osteocyt Hi, if this was helpful, please consider upvoting the answer (click the triangle above the 0 to the left). If you have any further questions, you can open a new post.

Answer (score 2):

You need `:` for select all columns:

```
meanMov.iloc[0:5,:] = value1
meanMov.iloc[5:15,:] = value2
meanMov.iloc[15:20,:] = value3
print (meanMov)
        0       1       2
0    23.5  -42.34   322.4
1    23.5  -42.34   322.4
2    23.5  -42.34   322.4
3    23.5  -42.34   322.4
4    23.5  -42.34   322.4
5      43 -764.56  6.4556
6      43 -764.56  6.4556
7      43 -764.56  6.4556
8      43 -764.56  6.4556
9      43 -764.56  6.4556
10     43 -764.56  6.4556
11     43 -764.56  6.4556
12     43 -764.56  6.4556
13     43 -764.56  6.4556
14     43 -764.56  6.4556
15  98.54  -26.64   86.45
16  98.54  -26.64   86.45
17  98.54  -26.64   86.45
18  98.54  -26.64   86.45
19  98.54  -26.64   86.45
```